# wpf use elements declared in style

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, wpf-controls

i'm in trouble joining styles and code in my form:

here is my situation:

my TabItem style:

```
   <Style TargetType="TabItem" x:Key="testStyle">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,2,6,2" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                    <DockPanel Width="120" x:Name="rootPanel">
                        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"  RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                        <Image x:Name="rootImage"/>
                        <Label x:Name="rootLabel" FontSize="18" />
                    </DockPanel>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

and here is where I apply my style

```
            <TabItem Style="{StaticResource testStyle}">
                <TabItem.Header>

                </TabItem.Header>
```

but: how can I set the values to my Image and label called `rootImage` and `rootLabel`?

Comment: You can use GetTemplateChild, but it depends on what you are going to achieve.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.gettemplatechild.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a class named `SomeClass`

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string SomeLabel;
    public string SomeImage;
}
```

Now change your style

```
<DockPanel Width="120" x:Name="rootPanel">
    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"  RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
    <Image x:Name="rootImage" Source={Binding SomeImage}/>
    <Label x:Name="rootLabel" Content={Binding SomeLabel} FontSize="18" />
</DockPanel>
```

Finally:

```
<TabItem Style="{StaticResource testStyle}" Name="myTabItem">
    <TabItem.Header>

    </TabItem.Header>
</TabItem>
```

And in the code behind:

```
myTabItem.DataContext = new SomeClass(); //create a SomeClass with proper label and image
```

Comment: thanks, is right, but if I have more than one tabitem, I need in the code create a class with proper properties... isn't there a way to do this into the xaml? thanks!

Comment: @ghiboz It should be done. But I don't know the proper way of doing it. You may use a `CollectionViewSource` which it's `Source` is binded to an `ObservableCollection<SomeClass>` and also use a special `ItemsControl` with modified `ItemsPanel` and ...

Answer (score 1):

Just like you did for your `TabItem`, you can have the style specified for your `Image` and `Label` -

```
<Image x:Name="rootImage" Style="{StaticResource ImageStyle}"/>
<Label x:Name="rootLabel" FontSize="18" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" />
```

In case, you want to change the `Header` look, you need to override `HeaderTemplate` and not entire `Template` -

```
        <TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image x:Name="rootImage"
                           Style="{StaticResource ImageStyle}"/>
                    <Label x:Name="rootLabel" FontSize="18"
                           Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
```

Comment: so my code will be like this?   `<TabItem Style="{StaticResource testStyle}">
 <TabItem.Header>
  <Image x:Name="rootImage" Style="{StaticResource ImageStyle}"/>
  <Label x:Name="rootLabel" FontSize="18" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" />
 </TabItem.Header>`

Comment: You have already declared Image and label in your template. Why you need to have them yet again in your header?

Comment: If you want them in your Header. You have to override the `HeaderTemplate`.